# Username/password written in Karate config file is not working in Post request in the feature file

Tags: json, karate

Config file : 
   var config = {
    env: env,
    baseurl:'https://***inggateway.**ls.com',
    username:'r**567@mai***ator.com',
    password:'****we12!',

```
Post request in feature file:
Given url baseurl + '/gateway/user/login'
 And header sessionkey = sessionkey
 And request '{"emailAddress": username ,"password": password}'
 When method POST
 Then status 200


It gives error :
Invalid grant or invalid username/password

I have tried many ways but nothing works.

Can somebody tell me how can I make it work? What is the correct way of passing config variables in 
Post request body.
```

Comment: I would highly recommend you to mask your credentials and production urls.

Comment: there are so many things wrong in this code sample. you have not understood how to use karate. please read the docs carefully and try again: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Comment: not able to find a single example where request of this type :   And request '{"emailAddress": a@a.com ,"password": password}'    is there. I just want to replace email and password with the credentials given in config file. How can i do that?

Comment: @amitmahajan if you looking for examples of that exact shape, yes you won't find them. you need to read how to create JSON that can be parameterized (the link above) and then you fit that to your use case. do try spend some time understanding how things work, it will be worth it I promise

Comment: I have tried that and was not able to do it and hence came to Stackoverflow to seek help. If someone could let me know how can I insert config variable value in the Post request json then it would be great. I have tried multiple options but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

As @peter suggested you can use [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions)

```
And request {"emailAddress": "#(username)" ,"password": "#(password)"}
```

you can observe the expressions getting changed to actual values in your log once you run the test.

Comment: have tried this already and many other ways but nothing worked for me.

Comment: response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid username or password"}

Comment: but if i hard code email id and password , then it works successfully

Comment: Even if i just print the username variable(given in the config file) in the feature file , then it prints successfully. I think the problem is with the double quotes in the request and I am not able to make it run.

Comment: From the log can you provide whats been sent in the request.. And which version of karate are you using?